# How to set continue counter from another counter (latex)?

Tags: counters

I want to set a counter (auto) like:

```
\newcounter{question}
\newcounter{example}
```

Question 1.
Question 2.
Example 3.
Example 4.
Question 5.
Question 6.

Can you help me. Thankyou so much.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome *Đặc Vụ* :))) Although using `question` and `example` from `amsthm` is the best way, one can always define a new counter and use it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}
\newcounter{yourcounter}
\newcommand\yourquestion[1]{%
\textbf{\stepcounter{yourcounter}Question \arabic{yourcounter}:} \textit{#1}\par}
\newcommand\yourexample[1]{%
\textbf{\stepcounter{yourcounter}Example \arabic{yourcounter}:} \textit{#1}\par}
\begin{document}
\yourquestion{How many continents are there?}
\yourexample{This example is for no purposes.}
\yourexample{And this is another example.}
\yourquestion{This is another question.}
\yourexample{How about the numbering of this example?}
\yourquestion{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In eget viverra eros. Donec commodo dapibus dictum. Etiam non ex placerat, fermentum ex sed, suscipit sem. Praesent facilisis vel quam non fringilla. Morbi sagittis tortor sed varius luctus. Curabitur ullamcorper ante scelerisque quam commodo, quis imperdiet sapien maximus. Phasellus bibendum, ligula eu tempor vulputate, tortor erat bibendum sem, eget lacinia mauris dui ac elit.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newtheorem{question}{Question} 
\newtheorem{example}[question]{Example}

\begin{document}
\section{Questions and Examples}

\begin{question}
$2+2=?$
\end{question}

\begin{question}
$\int \dfrac{1}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x=?$
\end{question}

\begin{example}
$2+2=4$
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Air...
\end{example}

\begin{question}
$2\times 5=10$
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's right what I need. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ĐặcVụXNguyễn, your welcome. But, I think you will use JoulV's answer.

Comment: @ĐặcVụXNguyễn, did you copy my answer? I will delete it soon.

Comment: @ferahfeza Please don't delete your answer!